# Laravel date format in submission form (d-M-Y)

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-4, laravel-5

In the submit form in the blade template I have the following date form and it works fine with default date like `Y-m-d`.

But I want to show the date like `d-M-Y`, I have tried to find a usable solution with out luck

Here is the code that works with default date:

Here is the model

```
public static $rules = [
    'birthday'   => 'date'
];

protected $fillable = ['birthday'];
```

Here is the Controller method

```
public function update($id)
{
    $kid = Kid::findOrFail($id);

    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Kid::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $kid->update($data);
    return Redirect::to('kids/list');
}
```

Here is the Blade template

```
{{ Form::model($kid, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['kids.update', $kid->id], 'files' => true], ['class' => 'form-horizontal']) }}
{{ Form::text('birthday', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::submit('Confirm update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

---

**UPDATE**

This works for all Laravel versions from 4.2 and newer.

For Laravel 5.1 and newer, you will need to install it as a [separate package](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) as it's no longer part of the Laravel 5 core.

It was decided that the html/form builder are not a core requirement for the framework so it was removed from the core. The package I linked to is the one that was included with the L4 core and is being maintained as a separate package for L5 compatibility and usage, so you're safe using that if you choose to do so.

Thanks to @Bogdan for this update.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need one date format for db storage and another for the user interaction, you need to process it before you display it and before you store it into the database. So you should do something like this:

**1. Convert the date value for your form input:**

```
{{ Form::text('birthday', date('d-M-Y', strtotime($kid->birthday)), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

**2. Before saving convert it to the database required format:**

```
public function update($id)
{
    $kid = Kid::findOrFail($id);

    // Convert birthday format to be compatible with database ISO 8601 format
    $data = Input::all();
    $data['birthday'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['birthday']));

    $validator = Validator::make($data, Kid::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $kid->update($data);
    return Redirect::to('kids/list');
}
```

If you want a more object oriented way of handling dates you can use [`Carbon`](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) which is already included by Laravel.

Comment: How are you typing your date in the input field? (also I've updated my answer with a couple of mentions related to handling datetime values).

Comment: Also, it might help if you posted the code responsible for creating/updating the entry to the database.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the code you posted.

Comment: Thx, it works like charm. in side the controller I did the same before, it seems the problem was inside the blade, but as I said it works perfectly, thank again and a plus from me. I will delete some of the comments and clean my question so other do not get confused.

Comment: Sure Carbon will be next step.

Comment: Yes it will work, but if you plan on using the form builder, you will need to install it as a [separate package](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) as it's no longer part of the Laravel 5 core.

Comment: I have working on L5 for while but not form part, why it is no longer part of it, is there a default one or alternative, or is the separate package is still the only way? thx

Comment: It was decided that the html/form builder are not a core requirement for the framework so it was removed from the core. The package I linked to is the one that was included with the L4 core and is being maintained as a separate package for L5 compatibility and usage, so you're safe using that if you choose to do so.

Comment: wonderful so I will soon start with it on upcoming project, I might btw update the question and the answer later, to reflect this information regarding laravel 5.x, it could be useful for others.

Comment: For future references, please have a read about Accessors & Mutators (Like Setters & Getters). That would be the correct way to define formats between user inputs and db storage: http://www.elcoderino.com/laravel-4-accessors-mutators/