# Setting bootstrap date format to yyyy-mm-dd in laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

in my laravel application I'm using bootstrap 4.

There is one of my forms I have a text field for picj the birthday

```
{!! Form::date('date_of_birth', null, array('placeholder' =>  __('texts.Date of birth'),'class' => 'form-control txt_txt','id'=>'from-datepicker')) !!}
```

This gives me date in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`

But I need my date to be `yyyy-mm-dd`

I even tried using

```
<script>
jQuery("#from-datepicker").datepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});
</script>
```

but this also gave me a JavaScript error saying `datepicker is not a function`

How can I set my date picker format to yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255392/laravel-date-format-in-submission-form-d-m-y
Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Funtion name maybe different try this..!    `.datetimepicker()`

```
$('#from-datepicker').datetimepicker(
   {format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}
);
```